# How to use the react native Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation(event) method?

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I'm working on synchronizing a text input field with the iOS / Android system keyboards so that it sticks to the top of the keyboard, in the documentation for the react native [Keyboard](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard#schedulelayoutanimation) module it mentions this method:

> **scheduleLayoutAnimation**
>
> `static scheduleLayoutAnimation(event)`
>
> Useful for syncing TextInput (or other keyboard accessory view) size
> of position changes with keyboard movements.

However I can't seem to find any further documentation or examples thus far, and my current implementation

```
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimationscheduleLayoutAnimation((event: any ) => {
   console.log('[TextEditor] keyboard event:', event)
})
```

Throw the following error:

> ExceptionsManager.js:179 TypeError:
> _reactNative.Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimationscheduleLayoutAnimation is not a function

Does any one have any experience with this method?

I'm currently on React Native **0.63.3** and testing on **iOS 14.2**, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

#### Edit

I was able to get the function signature by calling:

```
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimationscheduleLayoutAnimation.toString()
```

Which yields this definition:

```
function (event) {
    var duration = event.duration,
        easing = event.easing;

    if (duration != null && duration !== 0) {
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
        duration: duration,
        update: {
          duration: duration,
          type: easing != null && LayoutAnimation.Types[easing] || 'keyboard'
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Maybe this is an issue with strict mode in TypeScript?

Comment: Also have found this method. Have you figured out how to use it?

Comment: @likern I haven’t yet, I think you might meet pass in an Animated.Event but not sure...

Comment: Any update on this or an alternative solution to sync up the textinput and keyboard? @Asleepace

Comment: @AlexBishka haven't had any luck yet, will update this when I do!

Comment: Very curious to see how to use this as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why there isn't any sample usage documented for this method as it looks it might be useful.

Thanks to you I noticed that internally it used `LayoutAnimation`, here's the actual source for that method:

**node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/Keyboard.js**

```js
KeyboardEventEmitter.scheduleLayoutAnimation = function(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  const {duration, easing} = event;
  if (duration != null && duration !== 0) {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
      duration: duration,
      update: {
        duration: duration,
        type: (easing != null && LayoutAnimation.Types[easing]) || 'keyboard',
      },
    });
  }
};

module.exports = KeyboardEventEmitter;
```

---

#### Regarding the exception - you have a typo

```js
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimationscheduleLayoutAnimation
```

vs

```js
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation
```

#### `scheduleLayoutAnimation` does not work with a callback.

This won't work

```js
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation((event: any ) => {
   console.log('[TextEditor] keyboard event:', event)
})
```

---

#### LayoutAnimation

`Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation` takes an `object` parameter named `event`. Looking at the implementation it's just a wrapper over `LayoutAnimation.configureNext` so you can use that instead for the same effects. [LayoutAnimation.configureNext](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation#configurenext)

Only 2 parameters are used from the `event` - the name "event" is a bit confusing as it's used as a config for the animation

```js
const {duration, easing} = event;
```

You can call the function like this:

```js
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation({ duration: 500 });
// or
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation({ duration: 500, easing: 'easeIn' });
```

Right after this call you need to trigger something that will involve the keyboard. E.g. make it appear or disappear. See the examples in the linked documentation.

`easing` is an optional parameter that falls back to `"keyboard"`

- The available `easings` are from `LayoutAnimation.Types` - `sprint`, `linear`, `easeIn/Out`, `keyboard`.
- This is another confusing thing - knowing the fact that there's a "keyboard" why would I pass something else? I guess "keyboard" stands for the default easing the keyboard animation uses, and providing other values you can make it more bouncy...

I would assume the intended usage is something like this:

```js
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation({ duration: 500 });
Keyboard.dismiss();
```

or

```js
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation({ duration: 500 });
myInputRef.focus();
```

Since internally it just uses `LayoutAnimation.configureNext` the "scheduled" animation might get applied on something else that changes layout and not on the keyboard. If you don't interact with the keyboard it'll definitely be applied on something else.
I wouldn't have expected that - I would expect that if I schedule a keyboard animation and I don't use the keyboard it won't be applied on something else as layout animation

Anyway that's about it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a typo in your implementation -- you are repeating scheduleLayoutAnimation twice, when it should simply be:

```
Keyboard.scheduleLayoutAnimation((event: any ) => {
 console.log('[TextEditor] keyboard event:', event)
})
```

This would explain why you are getting a type error -- the method "scheduleLayoutAnimationscheduleLayoutAnimation" doesn't exist.

Comment: Nice catch haha, think was just a copy paste mistake at the time!